# Javascript rounding down

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

So I've looked into this for several hours before finally giving up and asking help.

I'm currently trying to form fill a character sheet for Pathfinder (D&D 3.5 equivalent) using adobe acrobat. I want to make it so when I fill in my strength score it will auto fill out anything that has to do with strength.

More specifically I need it to take **my ability score divide by two and subtract 5** for my ability modifier. But when I use 17 for instance as my Strength score my modifier is 4. I need it to round down not up.
I tried to subtract 5.5 instead and that works until its 10 or lower. At which point I have the opposite problem.

My current code is Strength/2-5

Comment: Is your number a int? Integers automaticly round down. Try a double. I'm not a big fan of W3Schools, but here is a link: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.floor()` like this:

```
var score = 17.0;
result = Math.floor((score / 2) - 5);
alert(result)
```

**Output:**

`3`

Comment: I doesn't quite work. I'm not the best at this of course.
I have set the decimal field to 0

Comment: Please update your question with code and sample input/output.

Comment: I'm doing this under Simplified Field Notation
The one that currently kind of works is Strength/2-5
examples of this is Strength=18 modifier is 4
strength=15 modifier is 3 (should be 2)
all odd numbers are rounding up
evens are correct

Comment: @bangpowwow—you can't "set the decimal field" for javascript Numbers. What result do you want? You could use `(score/2 - 5) | 0`.

Comment: The program is Adobe Acrobat Pro and it uses javascript for its calculations

Answer (score 0):

Original:
Strength/2-5
(it worked but it needed to round down instead of up)

Final:
var a = this.getField("Strength")
event.value = Math.floor((a.value - 10) / 2)

Thank you for trying everybody! Process of elimination gets it done